# Error using django-user-sessions to close a session in Firefox from Chrome

Tags: python, django, google-chrome, session, referer

I have a Django's middleware controlling when a user try logging in and exists another user logged with the same. My code checks if exist one more user logged and shows a template asking if the user want logout or finish the others sessions. If the user choses finish the other session, he is redirected to system. The request.path is useful to accept the requests only login and session/delete views.

```
def process_request(self, request):
    try:
        object_list = request.user.session_set.filter(expire_date__gt=timezone.now())
    except:
        object_list = None

    if object_list and len(object_list) > 1:
        if request.path != '/users/session/delete' and request.path != '/login/':
            return logout(request)

    return None
```

The error happens when from Chrome I try finish one session running on Firefox. It redirects to logout instead logging in the system. When I test the feature in localhost, it performs normally. Looking for the error I found that the 'referer' in request header is different when I use localhost and web from Chrome.

What can I do to fix this?